# Where are Services stored?

Tags: macos, uti, services

I created a service using Automator and noticed that it created a `.workflow` file in `~/Library/Services`. Is this the same file that handles the service that I see under (Application's Name) > Services?

If so, does that mean that I can add or remove `.workflow` files directly in that folder and have it automatically appear in the Services menu? Or do I need to restart in order for that to happen?

Comment: As a side note, services can also be defined in a .app bundle, they will be defined in the `Info.plist` for the app.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Services are in ~/Library/Services and yes, that is the file that handles the service you see in the services menu. Yes, you can add or remove them and they will automatically appear or disappear from the Services menu. Restart is not necessary.

Comment: More specifically, per-user services are stored in ~/Library/Services, and system-wide services are stored in /System/Library/Services.

Comment: Any idea where the "New Terminal at Folder" service is stored?  It isn't in either of these two locations.

Comment: @scottishwildcat, you don't happen to know where the service _Copy Link_ is stored?

Comment: @boredrandom I don't think Copy Link is a Service, is it? It appears at the top level of the context menu for me, not in the Services submenu.

Comment: @scottishwildcat, I thought the whole menu was made of services and we just had the ability to modify the submenu, but maybe not. (Was hoping to find it and add it to another service.)

Comment: @calum_b Do you happen to know where the built-in system service *"Search With Google"* is stored?

Comment: I've got a bunch of personal services in `~/Library/Services` but they're just not showing up in my Services menu, or in System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Services. I do not have a `~/Library/Services/.workflow` file. I didn't delete it so am wondering what's going on...?